# How to check if a table contains no zeroes

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write some code which would print "no zeroes" if all values in the table are non-zero integers. However, my code seems to return True even if there are zeroes.
Thanks in advance!

```
def zeroes(board):
    notZero = all(not 0 for i in board)
    if notZero:
        print('no zeroes')
    else:
        print('there are zeroes')
           
board = [[0,0,1,0],
         [4,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,2],
         [0,3,0,0]]
zeroes(board)
Expected : there are zeroes
Got: no zeroes
```

Comment: `not 0` is always true, did you mean `0 not in i`?

Comment: `board` is a list of lists, and a list will never be `== 0`.  You will need either a nested loop or to flatten the data before iterating.

Comment: `print( "Zeros? ", any(i == 0 for row in board for i in row))` if you want to manually unpack each row and check each one

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `all` with `not`, you can just use `any` built-in. Also membership check requires the format to be `<value> in <iterable>`

```py
def zeroes(board):
    if any(0 in row for row in board):
        print('there are zeroes')
    else:
        print('no zeroes')
```

```py
>>> zeroes(board)
there are zeroes
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
board = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]
all_zeros = True
for lst in board:
    if any(lst):
        all_zeros = False
        break
print(all_zeros)
```